# Oracle - Use Column Names IN a Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how to get the column_names from a table in oracle sql.

My question is, is it possible to actually use those column_names in a query?

I can get the column names like this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

But it just returns a list of column names I cannot do anything with.

Is it possible to use those in a query?

I need to query a bunch of columns in a table and need to grab the column names dynamically so they are not hard coded in there...

Any tips?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to do with the column names?  There are a variety of ways to work with dynamic SQL so your specific requirements matter quite a bit.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this:  'code' WHERE (table1.column_name = table2.MY_DYNAMICALY_ADDED_COLUMN_NAME) OR  (table1.column_name = table2.MY_DYNAMICALY_ADDED_COLUMN_NAME2) OR (table1.column_name = table2.MY_DYNAMICALY_ADDED_COLUMN_NAME3) etc etc  'code'      Where "MY_DYNAMICALY_ADDED_COLUMN_NAME are pulled dynamically from the table...

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with just raw SQL, you must use PL/SQL.

So you have to use a stored procedure and do something like that :

```
SELECT 'SELECT '||LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME,',')||' FROM /* your condition hew */' INTO myQuery FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE table_name = 'OFFER';
```

And then use `OPEN ... LOOP` to retrieve your data.

It's just a suggestion, and I found it very complex!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a dynamic sql statement, and use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE call on the sql statement you generate.

Comment: I'd appreciate justification of the -1 vote. This is much the same answer as I would have given. Nothing more specific could really be offered on account of the question being so broad. What, dear downvoter, would you suggest instead?

Comment: I did not downvote, but this answer is more appropriate as a comment than an answer.